# Cannot find symbol fail in Junit test

Tags: java, linux, windows, junit4

I have created Junit tests on my windows machine. I want to deploy these tests on a linux server. I have put the code in the correct directory and the necessary jar files in the classpath on the server. Locally the junit test runs fine, but when I want to compile on the linux server  e.g. the test initiateDeliverProcess1FileTest i get:

```
InitiateDeliveryProcess1FileTest.java:1029: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method fail(java.lang.String)
location: class com.hp.bes.junit.systest.InitiateDeliveryProcess1FileTest
                            fail("test fail - There should be " + numberOfFiles
                            ^
```

What can I do to make it compile?

update 1:

- I have junit-4.11.jar in classpath

Comment: Do you have junit jar in the classpath?

Comment: Have you imported what is necessary? (I believe `import static org.junit.Assert.fail`)

Comment: Yes, this junit class compiles and runs fine locally so I expect this should compile on the server as long as I have the junit jar file in the classpath

Comment: Can you show your actual classpath?  The only two causes of that problem are not having the static import or not having (the right version of) JUnit on the classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I was able to get it to work by adding

```
Assert.fail("My Message");
```

Instead of just

```
fail("My Message");
```

I hope this helps.